# How to create a customized text area in Java for Java code

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, intellij-plugin

I want to add GUI to my software and I'm trying to create a text area designed for java code.

In other words, I want to create a small java editor area. How can I do that?
I'm using IntelliJ and SWING if it matters.

Comment: To create a good editor for Java would require styled text, whereas `JTextArea` only supports plain text. Start with a component that supports styled text like `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane`. *"How can I do that?"* That's too broad a question for a Q&A site, voting to close.

Comment: Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for some basics of using text components especially a JTextPane which is what you should be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea

Its is a text editor for Java swing applications.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned, the standard `JTextArea` doesn't support stylized code, so you'll want to use another component. One possibility is a `JEditorPane`, which allows for HTML input. Here's the link to the documentation for that:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html

You'll have to specify the content to take `text/html`.
Then, you can use the HTML `<code>` tag for built-in HTML code display support. Or, you could create your own stylesheet or in-line styles within your HTML to display it however works for you. Either way, this gives you the flexibility to customize how you want your code to be displayed.

Comment: You don't want to use HTML for an editor. Use a JTextPane with attributes.

Comment: @camickr You're right, I was mostly focusing on the displaying of HTML.